# Java Syntax Question

Tags: java, generics, syntax

```
static ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> createFromResource(Context context, int textArrayResId, int textViewResId)
```

Can someone explain the syntax of `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

That's [*generics*](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf). It's a way of saying that one type's API can be *parameterized* by one or more other types. It's saying that the return type is [`ArrayAdapter<T>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) where T is `CharSequence` in this particular case.

For a *lot* more information, see [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html). You might want to start with ["What are Java generics?"](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/Fundamentals.html#What%20are%20Java%20generics?)

Answer (score 3):

That would be a use of [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/generics.html).

In simple, readable terms it says that you are going to receive an `ArrayAdapter` of `CharSequence`s from the call.

In not so simple terms, it means that you're constraining one or more members of the `ArrayAdapter` type to be of type `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayAdapter is a type declaration for the return value of that method. The bit with the angle brackets is a type declaration for Java generics. Read more about Java generics here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` isn't a class declaration... it's the return type of the `createFromResource` method...

Comment: You are of course, correct. Bad terminology is bad terminology. Corrected.